# A better term for 'going through'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms, american-english, british-english

I am writing an abstract for a conference, to present a software project. I want to say I will go through all aspects of the project and would like to have better wording instead of "Going through" in the following sentence:

> "_________ [Going through] all aspects of the project, ..."

I have the feeling it's poor English for an abstract (I am not a native English speaker so I may be wrong on this...).

I am looking for something maybe more figurative (?) that would give a better idea of describing all aspects of the project in the presentation.

Comment: How about that you will "review" all aspects of the project?

Comment: Yeah, there are other terms but "review" is by far the most idiomatic for that context.

Comment: Some other verbs with different shades of meaning may be suitable, such as:

"consider"
"discuss"
"examine"
"evaluate"
"have regard for"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the word **Delineate**.

> [Merriam Webster - Delineate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delineate)
>
> - To describe, portray, or set forth with accuracy or in detail.
>
> *I will delineate all aspects of the project.*
>
> *Our objectives need to be precisely delineated. We should delineate the steps to be taken by the government*

I have used this word a couple of times in my abstract for journal publications. This is a formal word and I think it sounds great.

Other more obvious words that might work are ***Outline, Present, Discuss, and Describe***.